# EXCEL IF / OR statements using ISBLANK

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to compare 5 Properties databases,
I've dumped them into Excel since the database can't use SQL, then took the time to overlap so that I can see who shares the same values

I am using formula

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3),ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3),ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(E3)), "NO", "ALL 5 Match")
```

to show me all 5 properties share this function,  but I have some 2000 lines where 4 of 5 or 3 of 5 match and I'd like to change the formula to tell me HOW many cells are blank in the field,  so if 1 Cell is blank it will list 4 Match, if 2 are blank it will list 3 match etc.

Thank you very much for any direction you can point me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forumla would look like

```
=5-(ISBLANK(A3)+ISBLANK(B3)+ISBLANK(C3)+ISBLANK(D3)+ISBLANK(E3))
```

Logicals results can be treated like numbers, where 1 is true, and 0 is false. So we sum up the true for blank, and subtract that from the number of possible cells.

UPDATE

Jeeped's answer with COUNTBLANK is even cleaner:

```
=5-COUNTBLANK(A3:E3)
```

Comment: WOW.  That was brilliantly simple.   I was thinking I needed to figure out IF/OR statements.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Applied to the work sheet, and conditional formatting set,  I'll be a day ahead of schedule now.   I've accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an Excel version of 2007 or higher the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22) might be appropriate to get the number of blanks or the the older [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) will return the number of non-blank cells.

The [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907) can return a result from a series of responses.

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTBLANK(A3:E3)+1, "none blank", "one blank", "two blanks", "three blanks", "four blanks", "five blanks")
=CHOOSE(COUNTA(A3:E3)+1, "none filled", "one filled", "two filled", "three filled", "four filled", "five filled")
```

The CHOOSE function works on a **1** based index so 1 must be added to avoid zero.

Comment: I Can only accept 1 comment,  But Your solution also works I applied it to the work sheet.  Thank you

Comment: No worries. Like many things in Excel, there is more than one way to count a blank.